# {Object} is out of scope

Tags: javascript

I want to avoid overwriting an object in case it exists already:

```
var myObj = myObj || {};
```

I do this because I use requireJS and it is not assured that the files are loaded in the same order on each request.

JSLint issues an error:

> "'myObj' is out of scope" (or "'myObj' is used out of scope")

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Are you sure it's this line throwing the error, and not somewhere else where you're trying to use `myObj`?

Comment: Define myObj as a global?